# EF Core, return entry or create and return

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a .net framework 4.5 project I am trying to convert to asp .net core 3.1.  I am having trouble figuring out a simple way to convert the following code:

```
var entry = db.mytable.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "myname");
if (entry == null)
{
    entry = db.mytable.Add(new mytable()
    {
        Name = "myname"
    });
    db.SaveChanges();
}
int myNewID = entry.ID;
```

After converting to .net core, this code throws the following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry<project.model.mytable>' to 'project.model.mytable'
```

Does anyone know a good way to address this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var entry = db.mytable.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ID == id);
if (entry == null)
{
    entry = new mytable()
    {
        ID = id
    });

 db.mytable.Add(entry);

    db.SaveChanges();
}
int id = entry.id;
```

As it was,  entry = db.mytable.Add(new mytable()... returns an EntityEntry which provides tracking information, not the actual entity.

Comment: Sorry after reading your answer I updated the question.  Will the entry var be updated to include the value of the identity column from mytable after adding?

Comment: Once you have called SaveChanges() it will have the table id column yes, as it is tracked. I have added that bit to my answer also.

Answer (score 2):

To add to @JMP's answer:

See: [DbSet.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.add?view=efcore-3.1)

In your code:

```
entry = db.mytable.Add(new mytable()
{
    ID = id
});
```

You assign the return of Add, which is EntityEntry<TEntity>, whereas earlier in your code, the "entry" variable is declared as TEntity. This is why you get the message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry' to 'project.model.mytable'

Comment: Thanks @dugas, was also adding that info just about the same time you posted :)